# js.Dynamic.global.require generating different code in scala 2.12.0

Tags: scala.js

**Example 1 :**

```
import scala.scalajs.js.Dynamic.{global => g}

val image1 = g.require("./images/thumbnails/like.png")
```

scala 2.11.8 - fastOptJS output :

```
this.image1$1 = require("./images/thumbnails/like.png");
```

scala 2.12.0 - fastOptJS output :

```
this.image1$1 = require(($m_sjs_js_Any$(), "./images/thumbnails/like.png"));
```

**Example 2 :**

```
    import scala.scalajs.js.Dynamic.{global => g}
    @inline def load[T](lib: String): T = g.require(lib).asInstanceOf[T]
    @inline def loadDynamic(lib: String): js.Dynamic = load[js.Dynamic](lib)
  val image2 = loadDynamic("./images/thumbnails/like.png")
```

scala 2.11.8 - fastOptJS output :

```
this.image2$1 = require("./images/thumbnails/like.png");
```

scala 2.12.0 - fastOptJS output :

```
this.image2$1 = ($m_Lsri_mobile_package$all$(), require(($m_sjs_js_Any$(), "./images/thumbnails/like.png")));
```

**Scala.js Version : 0.6.13**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known inefficiency of the Scala.js optimizer with code produced by 2.12. It is [filed here](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues/2626) and it has [a pending fix there](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/pull/2641). Note that the resulting code is still *correct*, although inefficient.